# Resilience4j + Spring boot @Retry not working with async methods

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito, resilience4j, resilience4j-retry

I have an `@Async` method where I'm trying to add `@Retry` but the fallback method is never being executed when an exception occurs. I am also trying to test this mocking that an exception is thrown, but as it never goes to the fallback method, it never success.

This is my code:

```
@Retry(name = "insertarOperacionPendienteService", fallbackMethod = "fallbackInsertarOperacionPendiente")
@Override
@Async
public CompletableFuture<String> insertarOperacionPendiente(final OperacionPendienteWeb operacionPendienteWeb)  throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    StringBuilder debugMessage = new StringBuilder("[insertarOperacionPendiente] Operacion pendiente a insertar en BB.DD.: ").append(operacionPendienteWeb);
    CompletableFuture<String> result = new CompletableFuture<>();
    HttpEntity<List<OperacionPendienteWeb>> entity = new HttpEntity<>();
    UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl("url");
    try {
        rest.exchange(builder.toUriString(), HttpMethod.POST, entity, Void.class);
    } catch (HttpClientErrorException | HttpServerErrorException e) {
        result.completeExceptionally(e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        result.completeExceptionally(e);
    }   

    result.complete("OK");
    return result;
}

public CompletableFuture<String> fallbackInsertarOperacionPendiente(Exception e) {
       System.out.println("HI");
       throw new InternalServerErrorDarwinException("Error al insertar la operacion pendiente.");
}
```

Test:

```
@Test(expected = InternalServerErrorDarwinException.class)
public void procesarOperacionPendienteKO1() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, ParseException {
    when(rest.exchange(Mockito.anyString(), 
            Mockito.any(HttpMethod.class), 
            Mockito.any(HttpEntity.class), 
            Mockito.eq(Void.class)))
    .thenThrow(new NullPointerException());

    this.operacionesPendientesService.insertarOperacionPendiente(obtenerOperacionPendienteWeb()).get(); 

    verify(rest, timeout(100).times(1)).exchange(Mockito.anyString(), 
            Mockito.any(HttpMethod.class), 
            Mockito.any(HttpEntity.class), 
            Mockito.eq(Void.class));

}
```

Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: One thing that I first noticed is that you catch all Exceptions. So there will be no retry IMHO

Comment: result.completeExceptionally(e); is like a "throw". If I use "throw" instead, it doesn't work too and if I put the method back to sync, it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks like this:

```
try {
    rest.exchange(builder.toUriString(), HttpMethod.POST, entity, Void.class);
} catch (HttpClientErrorException | HttpServerErrorException e) {
    result.completeExceptionally(e);
} catch (Exception e) {
    result.completeExceptionally(e);
}   

result.complete("OK");
```

So on the last line you always set the result to complete!

Change it to:

```
try {
    rest.exchange(builder.toUriString(), HttpMethod.POST, entity, Void.class);
    result.complete("OK");
} catch (HttpClientErrorException | HttpServerErrorException e) {
    result.completeExceptionally(e);
} catch (Exception e) {
    result.completeExceptionally(e);
}
```

Comment: It's executing the fallback now with this change but it's returning ExecutionException instead of InternalServerErrorDarwinException. Why?

Comment: Is your exception nested in the ExecutionException ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "nested"

Comment: If you call getCause() of the exception is your exception the cause?

Comment: And you are sure that fallbackInsertarOperacionPendiente is called?

Comment: Sorry I deleted my previous comment because I was wrong. If I call "insertarOperacionPendiente" from another method, for example from the test  where I catch the "ExecutionException" exception and do getCause(). I do get my exception

Comment: but if I call getCause() in the fallback method, I get null.

Comment: Yes that normal because in the fallback method is where you would throw the exception!

Comment: I understood it now, than you very much :)

Comment: I'm happy to help :-)